RxJS setTimeout operator equivalent
Is there a RxJS operator that can replace set/clearTimeout in this specific case:
this.mouseEnterSubscription = this.mouseEnterStream
  .subscribe(() => {
    this.timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      void this.playVideo();
    }, 500)
});

this.mouseLeaveSubscription = this.mouseLeaveStream.subscribe(() => {
  this.pauseVideo();
  clearTimeout(this.timeout);
});


Is delay what you looking for?

I need to clear it on mouse leave. Delay won't cut it.

What are you not satisfied with your current implementation?

You can use debounceTime to delay emitting until the indicated time has passed without receiving a new emission and you can use takeUntil to complete an observable when another observable emits a value:
const mouseEnterSubscription = mouseEnterStream.pipe(
  debounceTime(500),
  takeUntil(mouseLeaveStream),
  repeat(),
).subscribe(
  () => playVideo()
);

With this code we wait 500ms before emitting, but will bail out if the mouseLeaveStream emits first.  Because of the takeUntil your mouseLeaveSubscription doesn't need to worry about doing any cleanup work. We use repeat to "restart" the completed source (otherwise it would only emit once).
const mouseLeaveSubscription = mouseLeaveStream.subscribe(
  () => pauseVideo()
);

Here is a StackBlitz example.
